# how to get DTPerformanceSession working when 'libproc.h file not found'

Tags: objective-c, instruments, performance-testing

After adding the line

```
#import <DTPerformanceSession/DTSignalFlag.h>
```

I get 'libproc.h file not found'. 
This file is not on my mac.
I have tried googling it and it appears is should be included with Xcode.
I have tried upgrading xcode from 4.3 to 4.4 and still the same error.

I am trying to use the following line in my game loop.

```
DTSendSignalFlag("com.mycompany.mytracepoints.app.point", DT_POINT_SIGNAL, TRUE);
```

I have included the DTPerformanceSession.framework
Am I missing something?

Comment: We can now use "points of interest". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1271826.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using for iOS then comment out that line "libproc.h". The flags will appear but on the simulator only not on device. :)

Comment: It makes me wonder...  Why add this for iOS if you can't use it on devices?  The device's performance profile is the only one that matters.